# How to resize table view cell depending on a label content

Tags: swift, height, tableview, cell

I've looking for an answer and I'd had no luck. What I'm trying to do is to resize a table view cell height. I'm using custom cells with a picture, a label with some text and in the bottom of the cell, two buttons.

Text in label is very dynamic so I need to adjust the cell height. I've tried what I've read over here, something like: theLabelToAdjust.sizeThatFits but it doesn't work. I don't know what else to do.

I've tried too to use the heightForRowAtIndexPath en return something like UIAutoRedimension (something like that), it didn't work.

My custom cell's file with the IBOutlets is in another swift file UItableViewCell class.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I returned UITableViewAutomaticDimension and didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the label constraints to be constrained on all sides. Then in your viewDidLoad..

```
self.table.estimatedRowHeight = 50 // Always do slightly more than the average row height
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath create an object for your cell...

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellViewController
```

Make sure you create a class for your cell (in this case CellViewController) and set the identifier of the cell to something in the storyboard and call it as I did above.

Finally in your cellForRowAtIndexPath...

```
cell.label.numberOfLines = 0 // "Label" is the outlet for the label I created in the CellViewController
```

Comment: is cell.label.numberOfLines = 0 mandatory in cellForRowAtIndexPath ? I have set it in xib itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your constraints correctly, so top and bottom constraints on the label. You also need to set the label number of rows to 0. Also when you set automatic dimension, you should give it an estimated row height, eg:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: I'm not able to do it. I've placed that two lines in my viewDidLoad( ) but constraints are already set and number of lines is 0...